# XSLT transforming XML to another XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Books>
        <book bookID="b100">
            <categories>
                <category>Programming</category>
                <category>Learning</category>
                <category>Database</category>
            </categories>
        </book>
    </Books>
```

And i want to transform that xml document into this one:

```
<Books>
    <book>
        <bookID>b100</bookID>
        <categories>
            <category>Programming</category>
            <category>Learning</category>
            <category>Database</category>
        </categories>
    </book>
</Books>
```

I have more books but i only posted this one. I have done this xslt code here for that xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Books">
        <Books>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Books>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="book">
            <book>
                <xsl:element name="bookID"><xsl:value-of select="@bookID"/></xsl:element>
                <categories>
                    <xsl:for-each select="categories/category">
                        <xsl:element name="category">
                            <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </categories>
            </book>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The problem is that categories are not showing, i'm just getting their tag:**

```
<Books>
    <book>
        <bookID>b100</bookID>
        <categories>
            <category />
            <category />
            <category />
        </categories>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookID>b101</bookID>
        <categories>
            <category />
            <category />
            <category />
            <category />
           </categories>
    </book>
</Books>
```

**Any idea what have i done wrong in my xslt code there?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `xsl:copy-of` to copy categories.

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <book>
        <xsl:element name="bookID"><xsl:value-of select="@bookID"/></xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="categories"/>
    </book>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real change you want to implement is the transformation of the attribute `bookID` to an element `bookID` so I would set up a template doing that with e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="@bookID">
      <bookID>{.}</bookID>
  </xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 3 (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMem) or with

```
  <xsl:template match="@bookID">
      <bookID>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </bookID>
  </xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 1 (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMem/1) or 2 and then the rest can be handled by the identity transformation.

That way you have a modular and structured approach that allows adding further templates for any element or attribute that also requires a change.